# <p> is not in the result inside a PHP condition

Tags: php, html, wordpress, advanced-custom-fields

what is the wrong in this code that makes the  removed from the result

```
<?php if(the_field('price',$postID)) : ?>  
          <p class="price"> <?php the_field('price',$postID) ; ?></p> 
          <?php endif; ?>
```

The result show only the price without the p element

[image]

Comment: Pure speculation, because your question is lacking any details, but what if the function `the_field('price',$postID)` doesn't actually return anything, but only echo's the price? That could explain it. You should show the code of that function in your question.

Comment: <?php the_field('price',$postID) ; ?> return 880 in the screenshot what I need in the screenshot is <p class="price">880</p> did you get it?

Comment: Yes, I got it. Did you read my comment?

Comment: I should add WordPress and ACF tags to the question.
This function is to show only the price from the backend and it works fine bcause it show 880 but the HTML before it is not there, why this happen this is my question.

Comment: Do you understand echo and return are different?

Comment: @shingo
I understand, can you understand the difference between when I describe a result by saying return and the return of the function?

Comment: @KIKOSoftware I read it and you are wrong 
the_field is not a function that I created, it is a predefined ACF function to display the value of a specific field advancedcustomfields.com/resources/the_field

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just change

```
the_field('price',$postID)
```

By

```
get_field('price',$postID)
```

And Enjoy!

Comment: It would be nice if you explained, in your answer, why this is a solution.

Comment: I agree with @KIKO Software. This answer needs explanation. As far as I know changing both `the_field` to `get_field` inside the code provided in question would result in displaying empty `<p>` tags.

Answer (score 2):

Using [the_field()](https://www.advancedcustomfields.com/resources/the_field/) echos and [get_field()](https://www.advancedcustomfields.com/resources/get_field/) returns the value of a specific field. So with your provided code if you change both to `get_field()` then it will display empty `<p>` tags as you're not echoing them.

The solution will be to change the if condition to `get_field()` and the one inside `<p>` tags would remain `the_field()`.

```
<?php if (get_field('price', $postID)) : ?>  
  <p class="price"><?php the_field('price', $postID); ?></p> 
<?php endif; ?>
```

If you ever echo any tags then `get_field()` should be used.

```
if (get_field('price', $postID)) {  
  echo "<p class=\"price\">" . get_field('price', $postID) . "</p>";
}
```

*Any function that echos its value should not be used inside if statement's `(condition)`.*

Comment: This is indeed a better answer than the accepted answer.

Answer (score 0):

Your `the_field()` function `echo` the output, not returning the value as
@KIKOSoftware speculated. If it wouldn't `echo` and returned value instead, you'd end up with an empty `<p>` tag anyway, because there is no `echo` to output the result in your code.

If `the_field()` returned value, you'd need
use either

```
<?php echo the_field('price',$postID) ; ?>
```

or

```
<?=the_field('price',$postID) ; ?>
```

**So the answer is: check your `the_field()` function.**

Comment: Thank you very much, but this didn't help because the_field is not a function that I created, it is a predefined ACF function to display the value of a specific field
https://www.advancedcustomfields.com/resources/the_field/